# Closed or open subsets of $C[a,b]$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

$C[a,b]$ denotes the space of continuous real-valued functions on $[a,b]$. The metric associated with $C[a,b]$ here is $d(f,g)=sup[|f(x)-g(x)|]$ where the supremum is taken over $[a,b]$. $C^1[a,b]$ denotes the one of continuously differentiable functions on $[a,b]$.

I think the second is a closed subset of the first but I can't get my head around a proof! Can someone give me a plan, a hint or anything, so I can try this out again? It would be very helpful and clarify what I (probably) didn't understand.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I'm editing the post right now!

Comment: Consider $[-1,1]$ for example, and $\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}}$.

Comment: Why does the $n$ appear? I'm really confused about what exactly I need to prove...

Comment: Consider a sequence $f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}$. Also, Stone-Weierstraß.